# ¿Cómo obtener la HORA de un DATETIME? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

De un **DATETIME** sólo quiero obtener la **HORA**, ya intente lo siguiente y no funciona:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, notificacion_update) as notificacion_hora, notificacion_msj, notificacion_id, notificacion_status 

FROM notificacion 

WHERE notificacion_status = 1 ORDER BY notificacion_id LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Qué error te sale?

Comment: Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar. 0.094 sec

Comment: prueba esto antes de ejecutar tu query "use database 'nombre de tu bd'"

Comment: Listo, mira este error es el que sale ahora:

Comment: Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION DATEPART does not exist 0.093 sec

Comment: pon en lugar de "notificacion_update" esto '2017/08/25 08:36', te sigue saliendo el mismo error?

Comment: Si, :/ sigue saliendo el error que dice que la función DATEPART no existe.

Comment: DATEPART es de sql server, seguro estas usando mysql, intenta usar datediff te dejo la referencia https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: SÚPER, GRACIAS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando una función de Sql Server cuando debes usar una de Mysql, para ello puedes consultar la siguiente [guía](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), te dejo un ejemplo con el uso de datediff

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
    -> -31
```

Comment: Gracias Jorge! Me ha funcionado tu ayuda.

Comment: Todo un placer @Ricardo

Comment: Quiero restar la hora que viene en notificacion_update - la hora actual, pruebo con esto y no funciona, arroja puro 0: SELECT  DATEDIFF(notificacion_update, curdate()) as resta FROM tt_notificacion; & tambien probe con SELECT  DATEDIFF(notificacion_update, now()) as resta FROM tt_notificacion; ambas salen 0

Comment: En qué formato estas pasando tu variable?

Comment: La hora y fecha inicial es:2007-12-31 23:59:59 y la hora de termino es: 2018-03-06 17:44:09, quiero calcular la diferencia de horas entre estas fechas. Pense que con la hora bastaba, pero no, hay que calcular los días también.

Comment: Ya lo tengo, disculpa la pequeña confusión se debe usar otra función para la diferencia de horas, te respondería aquí mismo pero, ya que, es otra pregunta seguro que viene algún moderador a decir que no debo dar mas de una respuesta, te parece si haces otra pregunta? dejas el link para responderte ahí

Comment: ok, voy a hacer la nueva pregunta!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(varchar,notificacion_update,108) as notificacion_hora,  
notificacion_msj, notificacion_id, notificacion_status FROM notificacion 
WHERE notificacion_status = 1 ORDER BY notificacion_id LIMIT 10;
```

> si pruebas esta linea te dará como resultado la hora actual

```
select convert(varchar,getdate(),108)
```

lo que pasa con esa linea hice que obtuviera el valor getdate seria `06/03/2018 15:13:13` según sql y tu pc, entonces para obtener solo la hora el convert tiene una propiedad para convertir esa fecha en varchar, el codigo 108 es un "siglo" que permite obtener la hora de la fehcha antes puesta, en este caso seria `15:13:13` si quieren mas información miren este link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx#Tipos de valor devueltos

Comment: Puede explicar como llegaste a esta solución para que tu respuesta sea aceptada

Comment: Quiero obtener la HORA del dato que estoy consultando. Y no funciona porque es MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Puede probar con

```
SELECT HOUR(TIME(notificacion_update)) as notificacion_hora, notificacion_msj, notificacion_id, notificacion_status 

FROM notificacion 

WHERE notificacion_status = 1 ORDER BY notificacion_id LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: En la base de datos yo tengo este dato: 2018-03-06 15:51:53 Y el query me devuelve solo el 15,